# List comprehension with conditionals

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a string which may contain asterisks, e.g. "c * b *" (I had to add spaces between the characters as SO is not displaying the string accurately).

I would like to use list comprehension to check whether every **even** character is an asterisk. So the output for the above string would be True.

By contrast, a string like " a b *" should produce False.

How to do that?

EDIT:

I accepted the answer of @InfinityTM even though it was not exactly answering the question (I had to replace **any** with **all**). The answer of @RoadRunner is almost accurate, too - I had to change any to all and the i % 2 check to 1 (I meant - confusingly - the even positions starting from 1. My bad!).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
any(str1[i] == '*' for i in range(0,len(str1),2))
```

This returns `True` if any element of `str1` is an astrick.
Also, to get even chr of a string:

```
any(i == '*' for i in str1[1::2])
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the module `%` operator to check if the index is even. We can use [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) to get the index and the element at the same time, and [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) to check if *any* elements satisfy the condition.

```
>>> s = " a b *"
>>> any(x == '*' for i, x in enumerate(s) if i % 2 == 0)
False
>>> s = "c * b *"
>>> any(x == '*' for i, x in enumerate(s) if i % 2 == 0)
True
```